# How to install C headers on Ubuntu

Tags: c, header

I am using Visual Studio Code. Is there any python pip like function for downloading C header files or is there any straightforward way to do so. I am a beginner.

Comment: I don't know any. But the good ol' way isn't too bad. Download the header files then compile and link them with your program.

Comment: *What* "C headers"? The standard C headers are included with the compiler and the C library. If you install the Ubuntu standard package `build-essential` package it should be enough.

Comment: And quite honestly, there must be *thousands* of tutorials on how to set up Ubuntu systems for programming in C. What have you searched for? What have you found? What problems do you have with the tutorials you have found?